# {% csrf_token %} is empty string but {{ csrf_token }} returns a value - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, csrf-token

I have to submit a form via POST method. 
I added to my html form the {% csrf_token %} tag but from the DOM I'm getting this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
```

But if I type {{ csrf_token }} in the template I can see the value. 
Why can't I set my token in the form? 
This is my form:

```
<form action="{% url 'aj_upload_file' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a id="upload-file-btn" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success mr-2">
        <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <input class="d-none" multiple type="file" id="upload-file">
</form>
```

Thank You.

Comment: check your template backend. if it django - {% csrf_token %},  for jinja - {{ csrf_input }}

Comment: I'm using Django.

Comment: django settings can contains different settings, how templates should work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django

Comment: I have already set BACKEND to django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates. I can't understand why it doesn't work here but not in other my projects

Comment: Is `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` included in `MIDDLEWARE`?  Try stepping through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/) and make sure you've got thins set up correctly.

Comment: Yes it is, by the way this tag works in every template except for this one.

Comment: I fixed the problem getting the csrf token by the allowed cookies (getCookie function)... If anyone have the same problem, you can check the official Django documentation right here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: Are you adding this form into another template with an `{% include %}` tag? I was having this issue and that was the problem. I moved the `{% csrf_token %}` up to the main template and it's fixed. I also tested `{% include ... with csrf_token=csrf_token %}` and that works, but it passes the value only so you would have to construct the `input` tag in your included template.